# Why are Interface Mocks More Desirable than Subclass Mocks when Unit Testing?

Tags: unit-testing, oop, mocking

When a class implements an interface, then it is easy to mock, but, you have to create an interface for it.

You can also mock by subclassing and overriding.  If your base class provides a parameterless protected constructor,  then your subclass mocks are not tied to changes in the base class constructor.

At first glance, it seems like the subclassing method to creating mocks is more desirable than creating interfaces for everything, but obviously, that's not how most people are doing it.

So, why are mocks based on interfaces considered a better practice than mocks based on subclassing?

Comment: Strange question to be asking in 2015, as every mocking library has had first-class support for mocking classes for many years now. And, as far as I know and at least in the Java community, only one of the jMock developers actually encouraged users to mock only interfaces; other Java mocking tool developers did not insist on that.

Comment: I don't think it's strange if you're not using a mocking library.  That being said, I would definitely favor using a library to mock concrete classes than having to create interfaces just for the sake of testing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contrary to most beliefs, even if you do Test-Driven Development (TDD), you should still follow good design practices. The trick is to make APIs testable *and* well-designed. [TDD isn't a design methodology](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/12/22/TheTDDApostate), but a feedback technique.

Therefore, it's not a question of Interface *Mocks* versus Subclass *Mocks*, but rather a question of interfaces versus subclasses.

That's a really old discussion that ought to have been over back in 1994; in [Design Patterns](http://amzn.to/XBYukB), we learn that we should **favour composition over inheritance**.

There's a long discussion about this topic, but in short, in languages with single inheritance, basing an API design on inheritance is to constrain all future variability along other (yet unforeseen) dimensions. Inheritance in such languages is simply too restrictive. Since all major Object-Oriented languages (Java, C#, Ruby) have single inheritance, you ought to see most Object-Oriented code bases correctly avoiding inheritance.

When a design is based on composition over inheritance, it follows that if you use mock objects, you'll be mocking interfaces, not base classes.

Comment: I am struggling to understand this answer... "Composition over inheritance" is not about using separate interfaces, but simply to use an object of type A from inside an object of type B, instead of making B inherit from A. For a concrete example, consider Java's `java.util.Properties` class, which was (mis-)designed with inheritance from the `java.util.Hashtable` class when it should have just *used* `Hashtable` internally.

Comment: @Rogério Fair enough; there's a few implicit assumptions in my answer that could have been more explicit. My use of the word *Composition* is heavily flavoured by [Design Patterns](http://amzn.to/XBYukB), which states (p. 19) that "Object composition is defined dynamically at run-time through object acquiring references to other objects. Composition requires objects to respect each others' interfaces". When you follow the principles laid out in Design Patterns throughout in a single-inheritance language, inheritance is ruled out, so interfaces it must be.

Comment: Yes, but note the question is about [*separated* interfaces](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/separatedInterface.html), not about the general "interface" concept used in the book for the "composition over inheritance" principle. I am not saying there is anything wrong with this principle, just that it does not require a separated interface. In my Java-based example, the `Properties` class could/should have had a private field of type `Hashtable` (well, ok, `java.util.Dictionary`, if following the *other* principle from the book, the one about "code to the interface, not the implementation").

Comment: @Rogério Given a single-inheritance language, when you rule out inheritance, then how else (than separated interfaces) will you achieve polymorphism?

Comment: You would need to code to an interface which accepts multiple implementations, of course. But I don't see where the "composition over inheritance" principle says that polymorphism is needed. Going back to my example (which I would say is perfect here), note that the principle tells us that `Properties` shoud not extend `Hashtable`, but instead be "composed" of a `Hashtable`; no polymorphism or separated interface is needed for this.

Comment: @Rogério It's OK to interpret the principle that way. As I said, my answer made some implicit assumptions that should have been more explicit. In the back of my mind was *Design Patterns*, which is the earliest source I've seen for *Composition over Inheritance*. In *Design Patterns*, composition is used heavily together with polymorphism. Furthermore, if you add SOLID (AKA the *principles of OOD*) to the mix, it should be clear from OCP and DIP that polymorphism is essential in practice.

Comment: Everything I said is from my knowledge of the GoF (Design Patterns) book. I have issues with the "SOLID" principles (except for LSP, which is fine), but that would be another discussion. About composition x inheritance, I think I see where the confusion here is coming from: inheritance sure provides for polymorphism, but that is not the only reason people create subclasses; another main reason is to simply reuse implementation, and *this* is what the principle really is about. The intent of the GoF authors was to discourage the practice of inheriting just for implementation reuse.

Comment: @Rogério Your initial comment was that you're "struggling to understand this answer". The context here is unit testing with Test Doubles ('Mock objects'), which hinge on polymorphism.

Comment: Well, the question is actually about mocking separated interfaces versus mocking classes, and about a supposed preference (not clear from whom) for mocking interfaces. I don't see where polymorphism gets into the picture. Note that mocking a class does not necessarily involve the creation of a subclass with overridden methods. Several mocking libraries exist (for Java and .NET) that use other methods.

Answer (score 3):

When you subtype and override, you have the risk of missing overriding one of the methods you should have overridden, and actually running the "production" code, which you'd want to isolate away from your test.

When you mock an interface, 100% of its behavior must be mocked. Whatever isn't explicitly stated by mocking will just throw an exception, and force you address it.

Comment: This is not how mocking libraries work. They will not throw an exception for methods not "explicitly stated by mocking", unless it's a *strict* mock. But every mocking library allows the user to choose between strict and non-strict verification, so this is always under the control of the user. And, of course, this applies equally to the mocking of interfaces *and* classes.

Comment: @Rogério but the question wasn't about comparing strict to non-strict verification. It was about subclassing and overriding yourself (at least as far as I understood it)

Comment: I think it's a pointed answer to the question.  @Mureinik definitely pointed out some cons of subclass mocks.

Comment: This answer seems to assume, in the first paragraph, that one would *manually* create a subclass; but that's not stated in the question, and I believe in most cases developers use a mocking library for that. And then in the second paragraph it seems to assume the opposite (that a mocking library is used to create the implementation class), when it says that methods not "explicitly stated by mocking" would throw an exception; this "exception throwing" makes me think of strict mocks, as otherwise it wouldn't happen.